# What is the true equivalent of package.json for pip?

Tags: python, npm, pip

I know about `requirements.txt`, but that only includes a list of dependencies.
But what about the other meta information like the package name, author, main function etc. ?

Also i know about `setup.py` but since i want to programmatically access values inside, i need a configuaration file standard like yaml/json and not python code.

Did the python community come out with something truly comparable to package.json ?

Comment: Relevant links from pip documentation: [Build System Interface](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/) and [pyproject.toml](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/)

Comment: I personally recommend [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) for dependency management, which uses pyproject.toml described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Without 3rd Party Packages**

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

In the local machine. And in the server,

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This installs all the dependencies

**2. With a 3rd Party Package**

- **pipenv**

  I would use pipenv instead of pip. pipenv automatically generate `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` that is far superior to `requirements.txt`

  Install pipenv and setting it for your project

  ```
  pip install --user pipenv
  cd yourproject
  pipenv install package1 package2 ...
  ```

  to install packages from Pipfile is as simple as
  pipenv install
  Read more: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/
- **poetry**
  I have recently moved from pipenv to poetry because poetry has everything pipenv offers and much more. It is end-to-end, as it includes building and publishing of your project to pypi.

  installing poetry

  ```
  curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
  ```

  and set `.poetry/bin` in your path.

  ```
  poetry new yourproject
  cd yourproject
  poetry add packagename
  ```

  Like pipenv this generate `pyproject.toml` file that context all your requirements. Like Pipenv, to install your depence

  ```
  poetry install
  ```

  See more: https://poetry.eustace.io/docs/

  See Python packaging war: Pipenv vs. Poetry for short review of these awesome packages

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments on my question answered, it's `pyproject.toml` together with the `poetry` package management tool